Using a metal grommet instead of a buttonhole to insert the fringes into the garment
Are there any leniencies regarding using a metal grommet instead of a buttonhole to insert the fringes into the garment? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Are you talking about a [tag:tallis]?  If so, that would be an appropriate additional tag

The Minchas Yitzchak chelek 3:2 was asked this question ,and he goes through the sugya of min kanaf...l'maaseh he comes out that it would be permitted.

Thanks a lot for your answer. I live right next door to a Satmar shul, so I am sure I will find it there, b'ez''HaShem.

I have noticed that in two different batei midrash there is an old and a new version of the Minchas Yitzchak. The one in Nitra has it as you say: 3:2. The one in Brushov has the old edition which is divided up into fewer, thicker volumes and it is hard to locate the tshuva.
